# How to enable Chromium touch gestures in Electron app?

Tags: javascript, electron, touch

I want to use touch gestures to go to the previous page or the next, as default in Chromium. Is there a switch to enable this in Electron? I have only found tutorials for enabling touch events.

I installed "electron-touchscreen" with npm and loaded the new window as TouchscreenWindow, but I still have no gestures.

```
const TouchscreenWindow = require('electron-touchscreen');

app.on('ready', function() {


    const { width, height } = electron.screen.getPrimaryDisplay().workAreaSize
    // Create new window
    mainWindow = new TouchscreenWindow({title: "title", width, height, icon: __dirname + '/title.ico'});
    // Load html into window
    mainWindow.loadURL(url.format({
        pathname: path.join(__dirname, 'index.html'),
        protocol: 'file:',
        slashes: true
    }));
});
```

The Chromium switch is called "--overscroll-history-navigation", but enabling it also changes nothing.

Does the electron-navigation package in NPM maybe do this?